# Quitar focus parpadeante o establecer focus parpadeante en el inicio del editText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quisiera cambiar de foco al iniciar un activity o eliminarlo ya que siempre da foco a un edittext que no quiero

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="BIENVENIDO A HAPPYDAY
    CICLISMO MAS CORRER"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Ingrese su informacion para un mejor calculo de los resultados"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgGenero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMasculino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Masculino" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbFemenino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Femenino" />

</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPeso"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etEstatura"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEstatura"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rgGenero"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnContinuar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:text="Continuar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Nombres"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNombres"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ems="7"
    android:focusedByDefault="true"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etApellidos"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Año de nacimiento"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNombres" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Peso"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etPeso"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="kg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etEstatura"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etPeso" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:text="Estatura"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etEstatura"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etNacimiento" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="cm"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/etEstatura"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etEstatura" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="139dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Genero"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNacimiento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ems="7"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etPeso"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:text="Apellidos"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etApellidos"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etApellidos" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etApellidos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:ems="8"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etNacimiento"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etNombres"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etNombres" />
```

Comment: Mira a ver si es esto lo que estás buscando https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext

Comment: Si quieres quitar el focus entonces ¿no permitirias utilizar el teclado virtual? @NickLedesma